# django-cron task not executing automatically

Tags: python, django, django-cron

When I run `python manage.py runcrons`, the cron job successfully executes (prints 'Executed'). But it doesn't do it automatically. It's supposed to execute every minute as I've stated in the Class. Here's the code:

settings.py

```
CRON_CLASSES = [
    "app.views.MyCronJob"
]
```

app.views

```
class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 1

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'my_app.my_cron_job'    # not sure what this is supposed to be?

    def do(self):
        print('Executed')
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you also need to set up the crontab entry for the cron:

```
> crontab -e
*/5 * * * * source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc && source /home/ubuntu/work/your-project/bin/activate && python /home/ubuntu/work/your-project/src/manage.py runcrons > /home/ubuntu/cronjob.log
```

taken from [official documentation](http://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Comment: I'm running mac osx not Ubuntu will this be different for me? So my project from desktop is `project/bin/activate`.

Comment: I guess you'll have to install & configure one of the packages that provides cron (fcron, cronie, etc) and configure that

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Ayush's answer. This worked for me.

> crontab -e

This will open the editor, copy paste the following line at the bottom and save & close.

> */5 * * * * source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc && source /home/ubuntu/work/your-project/bin/activate && python /home/ubuntu/work/your-project/src/manage.py runcrons > /home/ubuntu/cronjob.log

In addition to this try rerunning these in your Django project directory:

```
python manage.py runcrons --force
service cron start
```